# Variable can't be used as setter because it is final (enum)

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to use an enum to be able to switch between themes using a button (in the Flutter SDK). I have an enum called ThemeMode with two variables inside of it ("one", and "two"). I initialize a ThemeMode called themeMode as ThemeMode.one.

```
enum ThemeMode {one,two}
ThemeMode themeMode = ThemeMode.one;
```

Then I try to create a theme variable that represents the ThemeData that the app should use based on themeMode.

```
ThemeData get theme {
  switch(themeMode) {
    case ThemeMode.one : return new ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    );
    case ThemeMode.two : return new ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      primaryColor: Colors.green,
    );
  }
  return null;
}
```

Then, when I try to change theme using a button I get the error: "'theme' can't be used as a setter because it is final".

```
theme = newTheme;
```

How should I initialize theme, or try to change it so that this works?

Comment: You must be leaving something out of your code. The main problem I see is that you only have a 'getter' for `theme`, and no setter. But the error in that case would be "No setter defined for 'theme'". Do you have some other code that could shed some light on the problem?

Comment: @HarryTerkelsen Here is a gist to the whole file: https://gist.github.com/g0bbl3z/233f23790c146036b076e002e35adae5
The commented method is where the error occurs.

Comment: why are setting the theme to a function name?

Either way, if you want the children to change the themedata

you should take a look at the stock app example here 

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/stocks/lib/stock_settings.dart

edit: nvm, you should create a setter function 

https://www.dartlang.org/resources/dart-tips/dart-tips-ep-10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that there is no setter for `theme`. There's only the getter you defined. It's unclear what you're trying to do. Do you want to use the logic of deriving `theme` from `themeMode` only when there is no explicit value given for `theme`?

You could add a setter and modify the getter to work like that:

```
ThemeData _theme;

ThemeData get theme {
  if (_theme != null) return _theme;
  switch(themeMode) {
    case ThemeMode.one : return new ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    );
    case ThemeMode.two : return new ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      primaryColor: Colors.green,
    );
  }
  return null;
}

set theme(ThemeData newTheme) {
  _theme = newTheme;
}
```